# How to insert records leaving out constraints

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have this query in a stored procedure:

```
INSERT INTO Checklist (AuditID, QType, Question, QNmbr, QID, ANmbr)  
    SELECT @AuditID, @QType, Question, displayorder AS QNmbr, id AS QID, 0 AS ANmbr 
    FROM Questions 
    WHERE Q_type = @QType
```

There is primary key constraint on checklist table on (`AuditID, QType, QNmbr, ANmbr`)

In questions table there are multiple records with same displayOrder in Questions table for few of the `Questions.Q_type` which cause insert to fail. Only one of them (anyone, but preferably TOP 1) need to go in Checklist table.
Is there any way query could skip over the constraints and insert rest of the records. Or may be I modify my select clause in insert? I tried that too without success. SELECT pulls up more than one record probably for same displayOrder in Questions table and try to insert them at once may be.

Answer (score 1):

You should filter wrong data before your insert

```
INSERT INTO Checklist (AuditID, QType, Question, QNmbr, QID, ANmbr)  
  SELECT @AuditID, @QType, Question, displayorder AS QNmbr, id AS QID, 0 AS ANmbr 
  FROM Questions Q 
  left join Checklist C on C.AuditID = @AuditID and c.QType = @QType and C.QNmbr = Q.displayorder and ANmbr = 0
  WHERE Q_type = @QType and c.AuditID is null
```

and I suggest you to reconsider your PK, maybe just use a single incremental column.

Comment: "reconsider your PK" - explain and justify. By itself this simply adds complication. And adding a synthetic key will not negate the need to enforce the natural key. Given the name, I suspect this table is not a hotspot so an identity column as PK does not seem to offer much (if any) benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The primary key is there to keep your data clean and prevent duplicates so it’s best to not try to bypass it. Looking at your select you are almost there, just a couple tweaks:

```
INSERT INTO Checklist (AuditID, QType, Question, QNmbr, QID, ANmbr)  
  SELECT DISTINCT @AuditID, @QType, Question, displayorder AS QNmbr, id AS QID, 0 AS ANmbr
  FROM Questions Q
  WHERE Q_type = @QType
  AND NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT TOP 1 1
    FROM Checklist CL
    WHERE CL.AuditID = @AuditID 
    and CL.QType = @QType 
    AND CL.QNmbr = Q.displayorder
    AND CL.ANmbr = 0
  )
```

Comment: This should work but this does not. I believe it is because NOT EXISTS goes true, but select (SELECT DISTINCT @AuditID....) pulls up 2 or 3 records and try to insert them in one go.